# Simple cookie will not set

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have set cookies before and they have worked just fine.  I have essentially copied that code over to another webpage on a different server and the code is not working.  The code is inside an if statement but I know its triggering because I've also echoed the code to the browser for debugging and it shows up.

```
<?php
    // Set some cookies
            $user = stripslashes($_POST['user']);
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $hour = 0; // Changed to expire on browser close, was time() + 86400;

            setcookie(Panel_ID, $user, $hour); echo "setcookie(Panel_ID, $user, $hour);";
            setcookie(Panel_PW, $password, $hour); echo "setcookie(Panel_PW, $password, $hour);";
?>
```

And yet when I get to my next page and do a check for all cookies that are present, those two are not set.

```
<?php     
echo "Cookies set are...";
print_r($_COOKIE);    
?>
```

There are a few cookies present then but they are from a forum on the website, not the two that I've set.

I even tried a very simple cookie to rule out variable issues or anything:

```
<?php
  setcookie(test,scott,0);
?>
```

And that one does not get set either.

Comment: You're setting the user's password in a cookie in *plaintext*?

Comment: No, its actually already been converted further up the code.

Comment: There, now it shows it here too ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

I found a couple of posts concerning cookies that mentioned that no HTML can be created before the setcookie.  I moved my code around and was still having an issue (no change).  I then moved my code so that it was triggered before another section.  Basically that page has an if(isset($user)) and an if not set.  I moved my if isset above the other section so that there was definitely no HTML being read before my cookies were set (even though it shouldn't have been since it was inside an if statement that wasn't triggered.)  That finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to setcookie should be a string... it looks like you're just typing the cookie name as a variable. Try putting quotes around the first argument.

Comment: No change, also, the same thing works on my other server with no quotes in the first section.